# How to force at least N digits in Python (Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, number-formatting

Let's say we have an arbitrary integer, `x`. I want to convert this number to a string; which is pretty easy using `str(x)`.

Converting the number to a different base other than base 10 can be done easily in numpy using `np.base_repr(x, base)`. But how do I force this to have at least `N` digits; if the number is `0` for example, `base_repr` will output just `0`. But what if I want at least 5 digits, `00000`?

I tried the padding setting in the `np.base_repr` function, but this seems to left-append extra zeroes, instead of adding them to fit. For example, `np.base_repr(2, base=2, padding=3)` yields `00010` instead of the desired `010`.

I know this is possible manually. We can just append zeroes to our string (left-append) until the length is `N`. But is there a library function in numpy, or some other popular library, that does the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use f-string abilities or `.zfill()` string method for this:

```
f"{2:03b}" # or:
f"{2:b}".zfill(3)
## '010'
```

`b` is for binary
`f` would be for float
`:3` would enforce 3 positions, however, padding would be with  .
`:03` enforces padding with zeros.

```
f"{2:03}"
## '002'
```

For different bases use:

```
np.base_repr(2, base=2).zfill(3)
```

or:

```
f"{np.base_repr(2, base=3):03}"
```

Comment: I don’t think this works with any base. Would this work in base `N`?

Comment: see improved solution